# File row confrontation

Tags: perl

I have the following problem: from a file (`file.dat`) with the following formatted datas

```
1 2 3 4
2 1 3 4 5
3 1 2
4 1 2
5 2 6 7
6 5 8
7 5 8
8 6 7 9
9 8
```

I want to find:

1. if the first element of a row appears in the other rows and if the first element of the subsequent rows appear in the row taken in exam;
2. if it exists then I want to print "*I have found the link x y*";
3. if the "*link*" exists, then I want to count how many times the other elements in the row taken in exam appear in the row where the link is present and print "*I have found z triangles*".

For example in this case when the program compare the first row and the second row and find that "*the link 1 2*" exists and then write also "*I have find 2 triangles*" (because in each rows there are the numbers 3 and 4).

For this purpose I have tried to write the following program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Data::Dumper;

############ DATA ABSORTION

my $file = 'file.dat';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";

############ COLLECT THE DATAS IN A VECTOR as vector[i][j]

my @vector;

while (<$fh>) {

push @vector, [ split ];

}

############ START THE RESEARCH OF THE LINKS AND TRIANGLES BY MEANS OF FOR LOOPS

my @link;
my $triangles;

for (my $i=0 ; $i < scalar @vector; $i++){

$triangles=0;

for(my $j=0; $j < scalar @vector; $j++){

    for (my $k=$i+1; $k < scalar @vector; $k++){        

        for(my $l=0; $l < scalar @vector; $l++){

            if($vector[$i][0]==$vector[$k][$l] && $vector[$i][$j]==$vector[$k][0] && $l != 0 && $j != 0) {

                 @link=($vector[$i][0],$vector[$k][0]);

            print "I found the link @link\n";

                if($vector[$i][$j]==$vector[$k][$l] && $l != 0 && $j != 0 && $i != $k){

                $triangles++;


                }
            print "The number of triangles is $triangles\n\n";              
            }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

The program print the right number of links but I found that if the number of rows is lower of the number of colums in the file, the program doesn't read the full row and this could be a problem for my link research. I think the problem is due at the `scalar @vector` upper limit in the for instrunctions (but I don't understand why).

The second problem is that it does't count the right number o *triangles* that I'am looking for... Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program does what you require. In addition it prints the three corners of each triangle when one is found.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $filename = 'file.dat';
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Cannot open "$filename": $!};

my %vector;
while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  my $root = shift @fields;
  $vector{$root} = { map { $_ => 1} @fields };
}
my @roots = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %vector;

for my $i (0 .. $#roots) {
  my $aa = $roots[$i];
  for my $j ($i + 1 .. $#roots) {
    my $bb = $roots[$j];
    next unless $vector{$aa}{$bb} and $vector{$bb}{$aa};

    say "I found the link $aa $bb";

    my $triangles = 0;
    for my $cc ( keys %{$vector{$aa}} ) {
      next if $cc == $aa or $cc == $bb;
      if ($vector{$bb}{$cc}) {
        say "Triangle $aa - $bb - $cc";
        $triangles++;
      }
    }
    say "I have found $triangles triangle". ($triangles == 1 ? '' : 's');
    print "\n";

  }
}
```

There are only two triangles in the data you show: 1-2-3 and 1-2-4. Following your algorithm results in this program counting triangles more than once, with the corners in different orders. To count each distinct triangle only once, change the line

```
next if $cc == $aa or $cc == $bb;
```

to

```
next if $cc <= $aa or $cc <= $bb;
```

**output**

```
I found the link 1 2
Triangle 1 - 2 - 4
Triangle 1 - 2 - 3
I have found 2 triangles

I found the link 1 3
Triangle 1 - 3 - 2
I have found 1 triangle

I found the link 1 4
Triangle 1 - 4 - 2
I have found 1 triangle

I found the link 2 3
Triangle 2 - 3 - 1
I have found 1 triangle

I found the link 2 4
Triangle 2 - 4 - 1
I have found 1 triangle

I found the link 2 5
I have found 0 triangles

I found the link 5 6
I have found 0 triangles

I found the link 5 7
I have found 0 triangles

I found the link 6 8
I have found 0 triangles

I found the link 7 8
I have found 0 triangles

I found the link 8 9
I have found 0 triangles
```

Comment: If I want to write the prints in a file how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

[ Only answers first question ]

`$j` and `$l` are suppose to iterate over the column indexes, but you count rows. The correct loops are:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#vector-1) {
for my $j (0 .. $#{ $vector[$i] }) {
for my $k ($i+1 .. $#vector) {
for my $l (0 .. $#{ $vector[$k] }) {
```

Comment: I have tried to rewrite the program with your suggestion, but in the second ( and 4th line ) the `$#{ $vector[$i] }` is read as a comment and not as the last number of the vector. I think there is an error :)

Comment: That really can't be You must not have used what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This question has two parts:

- Establish if a link exists between two rows
- Establish the total 'unique' numbers they share in common

---

Using an AoA is fine, but using a HoH makes life a little easier:

```
my %links;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    chomp;
    my ( $from, @to ) = split;

    $links{$from}{$_}++ for @to;
}
```

You can then check to see if the link exists:

```
print "Link $from $to\n" if exists $links{$from} && exists $links{$from}{$to};
```

And finding common "triangles" should be easy as well:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

sub get_triangles {

    my ( $from, $to ) = @_;

    for ( $from, $to ) {  # Bail out if link doesn't exist
        warn( "'$_' does not exist"), return unless exists $links{$_};
    }

    my @triangles = map {  exists $links{$from}  &&  exists $links{$to} }
                    uniq( values %{$links{$from}}, values %{$links{to}} );

    return @triangles;
}
```