# Find common elements in a file

Tags: perl

The program that I would like to write has the same aim of the [File row confrontation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203765/file-row-confrontation/15205173#15205173). This time the file I have is put in a different way:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 1
...
8 6
8 7
8 9
9 8
```

I want to find:

1. when the first element of a row appears in the second position of the other rows and if the first element of the subsequent rows appear alongside the row taken in exam;
2. if it found then I want to print "I have found the link x y";
3. if the "link" exists, then I want to count how many "neighbours" they share, where by eighbours I mean how many elements in the second column they have in common and print "I found z triangles".

The file is sorted.

In this case the program will start founding the first "couple" 1 2 in the file but reversed and it will find it at the 4th row (2 1). Then it looks if the 3 ( second row and neighbour of 1) is also present in 2 ( and it is the case because it exists 2 3) and so on. At the end it will found that the "there is the link 1 2" and it "found 2 triangles" (1 - 2 - 3 and 1 - 2 - 4). I think the answer sould not be so different from the answer in the upper link, but I don't know how to arrange the files from a file made like this.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have created so far?  Even if it is similar to your previous question, please post the relevant code here.

Comment: I don't know how to fill the array from the datas inside the file; for the algorithms I will use the same form as the [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203765/file-row-confrontation/15205173#15205173] answer.

Comment: Please rewrite the question in a more comprehensive way.  Also post your code here and link us to your code on www.tryperl.com so we can see the code running. You will get much better answers if you do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the problem is to find only the index of the inverted matching pairs? While reading this problem yesterday I had the feeling that grep may be of use;

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @parry;

while (<DATA>){
push @parry, [split(' ',$_)];
}

#@remind is reverse matched indices;

my @remind = grep {
my $ind = $_;
   grep {  #reverse @{$parry[$_]} == @{parry[$ind]} did not appear to work.

      @{$parry[$_]}[0] == @{$parry[$ind]}[1] && 
      @{$parry[$_]}[1] == @{$parry[$ind]}[0];

   } 0..$#parry 

} 0..$#parry;

grep { print $_,': ',@{$parry[$_]},$/ } @remind;

__END__
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 1
8 6
8 7
8 9
9 8
```

output is

```
0: 12
1: 13
3: 21
7: 31
10: 89
11: 98
```

from here you then want to find say for
    7[0] 7[1] (3 1)  with neighbour row 6 and 8 with col 2?

```
     6[1]
     7[1] (1 5) and/or

     7[1] (1 6) exist in the original set (in @parry)?
     8[1]
```

Which they do not so no triangle.